# Chilkat VB.net Google Drive 404 using shared folderID

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api, chilkat

Trying to get this working on shared Google Drive, I was able to get a 200 response initially but the folder was never written anywhere I could find.  So I added the parent and now I am getting 404 error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: [FileId].",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: [FileId]."
 }
}
```

```
       Dim gAuth As New Chilkat.AuthGoogle
        gAuth.AccessToken = GetGoogleAccessToken()

        Dim rest As New Chilkat.Rest

        '  Connect using TLS.
        Dim bAutoReconnect As Boolean = True
        success = rest.Connect("www.googleapis.com", 443, True, bAutoReconnect)

        '  Provide the authentication credentials (i.e. the access token)
        rest.SetAuthGoogle(gAuth)

        '  A multipart upload to Google Drive needs a multipart/related Content-Type
        rest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/related")

        '  Specify each part of the request.

        '  The 1st part is JSON with information about the folder.
        rest.PartSelector = "1"
        rest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")


        Dim json As New Chilkat.JsonObject
        json.AppendString("name", fFolderName)
        json.AppendString("description", "A folder to contain test files.")
        json.AppendString("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
        Dim folderId As String = "[folderId confirmed to be working]"
        Dim parents As Chilkat.JsonArray = json.AppendArray("parents")
        parents.AddStringAt(-1, folderId)
        rest.SetMultipartBodyString(json.Emit())

        '  The 2nd part would be the file content.
        '  Since this is a folder, skip the 2nd part entirely and go straight to the upload..

        Dim jsonResponse As String = rest.FullRequestMultipart("POST", "/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")
        If (rest.LastMethodSuccess <> True) Then
            Console.WriteLine(rest.LastErrorText)
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If


        '  A successful response will have a status code equal to 200.
        If (rest.ResponseStatusCode <> 200) Then
            Console.WriteLine("response status code = " & rest.ResponseStatusCode)
            Console.WriteLine("response status text = " & rest.ResponseStatusText)
            Console.WriteLine("response header: " & rest.ResponseHeader)
            Console.WriteLine("response JSON: " & jsonResponse)
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If
```

I see a lot of things buzzing around the answer but cannot seem to get this one. I saw adding `supportsAllDrives=True`, but was not sure where to add that....

Comment: Any reason your not using the google .net client library?  File not found means you dont have access to that file or it doesnt exist.

Comment: Inherited application that needs to stick around for a bit.  I am using a google service account and have added that to the share of both the shared drive at the root.  I got the parent folder id by looking at the URL and taking the last piece.  Is that a correct way to get it?

Comment: @DaImTo in reading your initial question and reflecting, I am not against using the .net client library.  Would you be able to point me in the right direction for using it with VB.NET? That's the piece of the app I cannot change.

Comment: I would love to see how you are managing service account auth on your own without using the client library.    Did you share the file with the service account via the google drive web app?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/66035919/1841839 or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/31279928/1841839  if neither work let me know and i will try and help you debug them.

Comment: @DaImTo I did share the file with the service account via the google drive web app. I am using Chilkat library to get the AccessToken. https://www.example-code.com/vbnet/googleapi_access_token_json.asp

Comment: Try running a [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) it should show you what files the service account has access to.  You are u sing a google drive scope right

Comment: So, interestingly after doing the file.list,  I can see the folders I was creating and could not find from earlier attempts.  It is not recognizing the share drive, it seems to be creating the folders inside the "service account's" drive.  I need to create the folder on the share drive.  I probably need this  "supportsAllDrives=True" not sure how to or where to roll it in.

Comment: Okay i must admit its been about 15 years since i have used VB.  where exactly are you applying the parents object to the json file metadata?

Comment: create the folder on the shared drive and make sure to share that folder with the service account.

Comment: I got it.  I will post answer.  @DaImTo suggesting to file.list helped me figure out that I need to add some queryParameters.  See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I needed to add the parent folder id of the shared folder

[image]

I needed to add these 2 lines for the file to be created on the shared drive.

[image]